# XML to CSV Converter VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

The program works fine with XLS, but not with XML.

**Task**: find PIE files with .xml extension and convert edited file to .csv.

**Problem**: I have everything working, converts, and retains. But the conditions where I tell him to remove spaces, remove empty lines - do not work. It saves an empty .csv to me from a table file.

```vb
'find the xml files in the directory
If Not curfold Is Nothing Then
    For Each fil In curfold.Files
        If InStr(1, fil.Name, ".xml", vbTextCompare) > 0 and (InStr(1, fil.Name, "PIE", vbTextCompare)) > 0 Then
            d = fil.Name
            Set wb = objEX.Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & d)

            If InStr(1, fil.Name, "PIE", vbTextCompare) > 0  Then
                'remove the spaces from the amounts
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "0.00"
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("D:D").NumberFormat = "0.00"

                'replace"; /" on " ."
                wb.Sheets(1).Range("K1").value=wb.Sheets(1).Range("K1").value & ";"
                wb.Sheets(1).Range("A:K").Replace ";", " "

                wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").value=wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").value & "/"
                wb.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Replace "/", "."
                '   wb.Sheets(1).Range("H:H").Replace " ", ""       

                'delete empty lines
                wb.Sheets(1).Rows("1:3").Delete
                su=1

                'delete column L and M
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("M:M").delete
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("L:L").delete

                nRow = 1
                'delete the extra empty lines at the end of the file
                Do While wb.Sheets(1).Cells(nRow, 1).Value <> ""  
                    nRow = nRow + 1
                loop
                wb.Sheets(1).Rows(nRow & ":" & nRow+20000).Delete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct Converter .xml in .csv

```
Sub XMLTOCSV()
Dim f           As String
Dim p           As String
Dim s           As Integer

p = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads" & "\"
f = Dir(p & "*.xml")
s = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        s = s + 1
        ConvertXMLtoCSV p & f, p & "Test" & s & ".csv"
        f = Dir()
    Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ConvertXMLtoCSV(xmlFile, csvFile)
Dim xlApp       As Application
Dim xlBook      As Workbook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.OpenXML(xmlFile, 2)
xlBook.SaveAs csvFile, 6
xlBook.Close False
xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```